# Easiest Deployment (non web) - SQL Server or MS Access MDB?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ms-access, deployment

I created a program using C# (Visual Studio) Winforms. I'm about 60% of the way, and it has been connecting to a `.MDB` file (MS Access). No issues, all working well.

I was convinced by a programming 'expert'/friend that I should really be using SQL Server Express and it was more suitable to my app, thus I spent about 6 hrs switching the program to SQL Server (e.g. rewriting the variables for parameters and changing some SQL specific code).

I have worked on it and now its about... 85% done and I'm putting more serious thought into deployment and I really think I've made a mistake and deployment is going to far more complex than a basic `.mdb` file.

Below is some details about the program:

- The program will run in pharmacies in Australia. It cannot be web based due to specific online uploading medical info that I don't want to deal with, therefore I want it to run on a local computer within each pharmacy.
- Each 'server' will probably have between one and 7 other computers connecting
- The program is not going to be used often. Potentially between 700 and 7000 records added per year! (so size will rarely be an issue).
- There is a bit of "update" SQL happening, but really, not masses of new records.
- All computers are running Windows
- It needs to be installed by the pharmacy staff, not an IT expert.
- Setup and install being easy is the priority here.

Now not that this is a good excuse but there are a number of other pharmacy apps that rely on a basic `.mdb` file and these are much larger companies than mine.

My gut instinct is:

- `.MDB` is just a file, just install the MS Access runtime and away you go
- SQL Server is more complex, needs a server setup properly and may be a HUGE deterrant to using my program

I hope that others can read this in the future and get their own idea on a choice between `.mdb` and SQL Server in the future!

PS: deployment for `.MDB`: create a SHARED folder on the server computer. I was told this is going to be complex. Is that correct?

Comment: If you have **multiple computers** connecting to your database at any given location, I would **DEFINITELY** opt for SQL Server. MS Access has a very poor track record to handling / working with multiple clients and is prone to file corruption and other messy issues - it's a **file-based** solution - not a **real** database. It might be easier to deploy initially, but it'll be a maintenance/support nightmare in the long run

Comment: Thanks @marc_s . My concern then, is how do i get them to install SQL server + deploy my DB? Do they literally need to go through all the SQL express install steps etc?? They arent going to be able to handle it and no one will use my software

Comment: If you use a capable installer software, you could most likely install SQL Server Express silently, in the background, using default values, and offer an "expert mode" if someone really wanted to change any of those settings. Check out using SQL Server Express as a *dependency* in your Windows Installer, and Google or Bing for "silent installation" for SQL Server Express

Comment: @marc_s Thanks mate, exactly kind of advice/direction i was after.  I do truly believe sqlserver is the best idea, but i also know fickle pharmacists brains and know that if it goes 'complicated" they will just bail and not want to install.

Comment: See e.g. http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/howto-install-sql-server-express.html

Comment: @marc_s how do i add you comment as an answer?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't install silently in the background except for local use, while you need a server install. So it not that simple as a linked mdb file.

Comment: Also, you will need firewall adjustments on the server hosting the SQL Server. This is not be handled by a common user.

Comment: Thanks Gustav. But if I have a "Sql install - Myprogram Database" installer, would that be Easy or still complicated for a non-tech person?

Comment: See this makes it sound way more difficult than mdb

Comment: It could be easy, that depends on the quality and testing of the installer. But if anything fails, no common user will have a clue of what to do.

Comment: "It needs to be installed by the pharmacy staff, not an IT expert." and "Each 'server' will probably have between one and 7 other computers connecting" do not mix. If those 8 existing computers do not have a (network) adminsitrator, I would doubt they could get a simple HFS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_File_Server) running and reachable from all clients. And as so many other said, that sheer amount of client screams for using a proper client/central server model. Or making it a pure "local storage only" application installed on one computer, that they have to share physically.

Comment: Really appreciating the feedback everyone.
Christopher - although i do understand where you are coming from, Methsof (example) is a company that has a program called "DD Book".  This program asks if the install is the server or client. If its the server it installs an MDB and creates a share on that computer .  Then when you install a client it just asks for the location of the server (and you choose from the windows explorer network panel that appears)>
This program is widely used in australia and installed in a matter of minutes by the pharmacy staff.
This is what i envisaged for me..

Comment: Then you have answered your own question. As you describe it, the install can be carried out by a non-techie. You might even hijack a "DD Book" install using the same shared folder on the server for your mdb file, and - on clients - use the existing shared drive or UNC path.

Comment: I've just checked out SQL CE and wow it is rough.  So many issues and errors exceptions popping up because it can't process even some basic things that access can!
eg. cant do subqueries with scalar results etc.
Converting back to access would be much easier than going to an unsupported SQL version... How about SQL Lite or If im doing that i may as well be looking at SQL express?

Comment: @Gustav in your opinion with what I've said, should i potentially be looking just reverting to access and then do some serious testing to make sure im not causing DB corruption??

Comment: My 2 cents: with the sort of minimal activity you describe, I would go for the .mdb backend. IIRC, mdb corruption is mostly the result of unstable network connections + directly editing data in bound forms or tables. With your frontend not being Access, you will be doing all INSERTs/UPDATEs via SQL, I assume?

Comment: Thanks Andre, yes all are SQL updates, nothing bound, all in C# using con strings etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file based system like Access can work well if you load is light and in general limited to say 5 users (this sounds like about 90% of your example cases). Also, you don’t need to install the Access runtime since in fact you are NOT using Access, but using the JET (now called ACE) database engine. In other words given that you program is written in C#, then you don’t have to install Access, but ONLY install the ACE database engine (that assumes accDB file format).

And you can well easy include the ACE database engine as part of your application install. I should also point out that SQL server just writes to a plan Jane windows file and is also subject to corruption. A Bing search of mdb file corruption produces about 70,000 hits. A search for SQL file corruption results in a WHOPPING 69 MILLION hits!!!!

So given such a light workload then using the JET or ACE database engine is a reasonable choice from what you given so far. The idea here that you must use SQL or a server based database engine is a beyond stupid recommendation based on your typical use scenarios you outlined.

I should also point out that you CLEARY stated that a typical install will NOT have a dedicated server running. In other words the station running SQL server will ALSO be used as a general workstation. This ALSO suggests that some sites will have RATHER limited computers. Installing SQL server on such limited workstations will often cause MORE support issues then you gain by using a server based database system. This is really an issues of the right horse for the right course. You don’t use a huge diesel transport truck to deliver one pizza.

Installing SQL server on such machines could wind up causing MORE problems than using a file based database engine like ACE/JET.

However, given that you already changed your code to use SQL server, there are options for silent installs of SQL server.

However SQL server will have to be installed ONLY on one of the workstations. So when your software is to be installed, you likely have to break it down into two parts. This certainly will “increase” the setup complexity of your software. So now a “customer” will have to decide and figure out what station to “setup” as the database server. In effect you going to have COSTLY human time support calls as a result of this choice.

So a few things:

Ignore the advice here about un-reliability of using a file based database. I had multiple clients running 5 workstations and using a file share databases for OVER 10+ years and never one issue. As I noted a simple search on SQL server corruption yields 100 to 1000 times more hits on the internet.

So SQL server as part of your setup will significantly increase your support costs and setup costs. Furthermore such an install will OFTEN require that you enable correct ports on that workstation that is to run SQL server (and the default express install does not have TC/IP enabled for use outside of that workstation).

Also keep in mind that typical pharmacies etc. only have about 2-5 workstations and they RARELY have a domain. Regardless of the “domain” issue, this really means you be using SQL logons as opposed to windows authentication. So this NOW means you ALSO have to setup a user + logon on the sql server (again, not too hard, but these issues are simply issues that have to be taken care of and have to be done is a “user” friendly way – else you chew up valuable human support dollars for a simply silly program install).

If your typical setup was 10 stations and you expected a “higher” workload and data volume then what you given so far, then I would without doubt suggest that you spend the extra R&D, extra setup costs, and extra support costs and adopt SQL server.

However given the information so far, then as an intelligent and well thought out choice, using the JET (now ACE) database engine in a file share mode is a RATHER good choice.

As I noted, you do not need to install Access on these machines and I would suggest that you don’t. You only need the database engine and there is an install designed to be used with Visual studio etc. that can be found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

So you don’t need nor want to install Access – you are not using Access but using the default database engine that ships with Access and it been a separate system and download for over 20 years in this industry.

The major compelling advantages of the file share system is zero setup hassles and not having to setup + install + maintain SQL server on one of the workstations.

Comment: Thanks Albert. To be very honest what you said is how I have felt for the past 9 weeks of development but couldn't explain it in those terms.  100% we are looking at each chemist having 20-150 patients in the system, with one record being added per patient per week.   That's 10,000 records in one table a YEAR.. which yes is such a low usage for an Sql server.  I appreciate your response and it makes me feel far more confident to move back to an accdb file.... or mdb?

Comment: Yes, Albert provided the answer. Many installations out there with a shared accdb or mdb run extremely well for years with about zero issues. The accdb format has a handful of features mostly useful when used with an Access frontend, so you could safely stick with the mdb format.

Comment: I run 5 user tour reservation system for 10 years on a sites that had 50+ highly related tables and is used interactively ALL day long. Table sizes are relative small in the 50,000 – 80,000 records in some (so a lightweight application with only 160 forms). Many “complex” commercial applications such as Simply Accounting (now SAGE) also use the JET database engine. (Access can open Simply Accounting files).  Simply accounting NEVER suffered a “general” reputation for file corruption in the marketplace. A point exists to avoid JET,  but I don’t believe you reached that point.

Comment: One advantage of mdb format is all versions of windows have the JET database engine installed by default - so you don't have to install anything at all - they are included as part of windows. If you go with accDB format, then you have to install the connective components from the above link.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple computers connecting to your database at any given location, I would DEFINITELY opt for SQL Server.

MS Access has a very poor track record to handling / working with multiple clients and is prone to file corruption and other messy issues - it's a file-based solution - not a real database. It might be easier to deploy initially, but it'll be a maintenance/support nightmare in the long run.

If you use a capable installer software, you could most likely install SQL Server Express silently, in the background, using default values, and offer an "expert mode" if someone really wanted to change any of those settings. Check out using SQL Server Express as a dependency in your Windows Installer, and Google or Bing for "silent installation" for SQL Server Express

Comment: Marc, this is _way_ too simplified and cannot go for an answer. Our clients have an excellent track record for running shared mdb/accdb databases with a handful of users. As with many other things: it depends.

Comment: Access is barely one step above using .csv files your Database Files. It is a significant step up, but still a far cry from even SQL Server Express. Wich is a far cry from a costly DBMS Solution. Really it mostly comes down to the sheer networking scale involved. 7 Clients and 1 Server needs at least a network administrator to install it and debug common issues. And once you have that, SQL is not that daunting anymore.

Comment: So perhaps i can piggyback off a situation.. There is a program that 60% of chemists in australia use that already has sql server installed for.  They would most likely install my program db on that same server PC thus i just have to install my db.  Am i correct in saying that?

Comment: SO i just installed another program that i used in pharmacy.  It installed in about 1 minute, ran some .SQL files (queries i guess building a DB?) and then is ready to use after a licence key addition.
The program points towards an .SDF file, but not towards an SQL SERVER database.  Is this an option?

Comment: k so thats SQL CE.. This seems right up my alley.  Am i wrong in saying that?  Seems better than access, but is single file so i can backup easier with programming + it is a "sql similar" procedure so less corruption?

Comment: @Marc: Searching for _sql server database corruption_ returns nearly twice as many: 3,64 mio. These figures leads to nowhere, and you should know that. Each scenario and its precautions is different, and there is no fits-all solution; that would be too easy. In many cases SQL Server (Express) is perfect, even the LocalDb install can be, in many cases a shared mdb/accdb file will fit; and sometimes neither will.

Comment: _SQL Server Compact_ is for _single user_ only. Apart from that severe limitation, you can regard it as an Access accdb file. The major difference is, that is uses the same SQL syntax that SQL Server does, which is somewhat different from that of Access SQL.